# Given Concepts, are SFINAE helpers still in the spec as non-deprecated?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++-concepts, c++20

It appears that [Concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) can do everything you could have done using SFINAE based techniques, only much better. The list of advantages includes increased readability of *overload resolution* and enabling to make *compiler diagnostics* substantially less verbose.

One option, given that all of [these *Concepts*' features](http://eel.is/c++draft/concepts) are [already part of the new draft](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/6ngkgc/2017_toronto_iso_c_committee_discussion_thread/), is that some or [all of these SFINAE related helper templates](http://eel.is/c++draft/meta.type.synop) be declared deprecated.

My main concern here is *feature fragmentation*.

My question is whether such a proposal for deprecation has in fact been submitted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That seems like a rather pointless thing to do at this point. There is *a lot* of code out there using these templates, they won't be removed in the foreseeable future anyway.

Even removing trigraphs and the conversion from string literal to non-constant `char*` took quite a while, and at least the former was not even undisputed. (IBM wanted to keep them iirc.) Those templates have and had valid uses in current modern C++; they are here to stay<sup>†</sup>.

Note that deprecating a feature in the C++ standard is a fairly drastic step, placing it under review for future removal. It is meant to be a temporary state; either the feature gets removed at some point, or is restored to be non-deprecated:

> With the release of a new C++ standard, we get an opportunity to revisit the features identified for deprecation, and consider if we are prepared to clear any out yet, either by removing completely from the standard, or by reversing the deprecation decision and restoring the feature to full service.
>
> **In an ideal world, the start of every release cycle would cleanse the list of deprecated features entirely**, allowing the language and library to evolve cleanly without holding too much deadweight. In practice, C++ has some long-term deprecated facilities that are difficult to remove, and equally difficult to rehabilitate. Also, with the three year release cadence for the C++ standard, we will often be considering removal of features whose deprecated status has barely reached print.

From [P0619R3](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0619r3.html), emphasize mine.

---

<sup>†</sup>At least for now. I'm not a member of the committee, so I can only speculate, but I would not rule out the possibility of deprecation at some point in the future, after concepts have settled in and if it becomes evident that the old helper templates do more harm than good.

Comment: I fully concur with your perspective, except for being pointless -- isn't having too many things to accomplish the same objective a bad thing from a language design perspective? Besides, declaring as deprecated definitely does not entail removing dependent code.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist That might be true, but what I'm saying is that it's pointless to deprecate features you cannot remove anyway. You might just as well leave them alone and tell people to use the new feature in new code. Which is what is done.

Comment: But isn't declaring deprecated a means of telling people exactly that?

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist As far as I'm aware, that's not how the committee uses it. It's used as "This is a candidate for future removal". See e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0619r3.html

Comment: I see! great sourcing here. I feel like it was a good decision to include the term *deprecated* in the question title.

Comment: Having said that, and already accepted the educated answer : ) I wonder if this: ".. and consider if we are prepared to clear any out *yet,*" from your quote, cannot be interpreted as if you can leave stuff on this list for as ling as needed, and so deprecation could eventually serve as a means to let everyone know the intentions, but that we'll probably wait as long as needed about it.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I would not rule out the possibility of deprecation at some point in the future, after concepts has settled in and has proven to be generally superior in every use case of the old SFINAE templates, either. But right now, I really don't see it happening unless you can prove some rather significant harm caused by the old templates.

Comment: Roger that, on point as far as I'm concerned -- my question was about this draft and your'e leaving the possibility of future deprecation and just saying that this time is too early. Perhaps a different phrasing of the first sentence in the answer would better adhere to this reasoning, instead of saying it's pointless. As is it even harmful or problematic at best given your official quote about deprecation (as opposed to just redundant). But that maybe in the future, and so on...